# Mysql string to date with given format containing a timezone specifier

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a string column in my database as

```
Wed Aug 13 17:51:06 GMT+05:30 2014
```

Can i cast this to date and use this in where clause to get records

```
where
Timecolumn >( CURDATE()-7)
```

Notice that the timezone specifier `GMT+05:30` comes between the time-of-day string and the four digit year string.

I am running this query in phpmyadmin but i get no results and yes they do exist

```
 SELECT * FROM `calldetails` WHERE STR_TO_DATE('date', '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s %x %Y')>(CURDATE()-7)
```

Also date is name of my column here

Comment: Can you give me the query?

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: STR_TO_DATE(Wed Aug 13 17:51:06 GMT+05:30 2014, %a %b %d %H:%i:%s %x');

Comment: Its not a duplicate the format is a lot different thats where i am struggling

Comment: Well, it's like asking how to add 1 and 2 and claiming that `2+3` doesn't tell you how.

Comment: Yeah than why don't you answer it already

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Thanks for the metaphor. I couldn't even find words to explain him why and how he's wrong

Comment: Yeah not every one has English as primary language.And please don't go away from topic

Comment: 'ang on. This datestamp has the timezone specifier in the middle. It's not as trivial as it looks.

Comment: Fair enough. But please note that most relevant info was not present in the original question, thus my feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `substr()` to excise the timezone data.
Also `CURDATE() - 7` should be `SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7`

```
select
    concat(substr(str, 1, 19),substr(str, 30)) as str_sans_tz,
    str_to_date(concat(substr(str, 1, 19),substr(str, 30)),
      '%a %b %e %H:%i:%s %Y') date
from mytable
```

Output (pre and post parsing):

```
|              STR_SANS_TZ |                          DATE |
|--------------------------|-------------------------------|
| Wed Aug 13 17:51:06 2014 | August, 13 2014 17:51:06+0000 |
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5aab6/5)

Applied to your query:

```
SELECT * FROM `calldetails`
WHERE str_to_date(concat(substr(`date`, 1, 19), substr(`date`, 30)), '%a %b %e %H:%i:%s %Y') > SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 7)
```

Comment: You didn't say you have multiple timezones. It is acceptable to ignore the timezone?

Comment: yeah we can ignore it

Comment: well frankly i didn't understand a thing. I didn't even know we can do that in sql.Can you change this query according to my query in question.Please

Comment: It works if i remove the -7 part. Do i have to add something more than -7?