# How to convert varchar date (Mon, 02 Jan 2017 15:46:23 GMT) to date formated data in mysql

Tags: mysql

In my database table one field `upload_datetime` is there and it is having a value like **Mon, 02 Jan 2017 15:46:23 GMT**. I want to get a formatted date like `2017-01-02 15:46:23`. Please somebody help me with getting it in select query.

I tried with `STR_TO_DATE,CAST` but I am not getting any output. It's returning `NULL`.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286335/mysql-string-to-date-with-given-format-containing-a-timezone-specifier

Comment: What is the type of the `upload_datetime` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. after doing some R&D i found the way.Thanks all for your comment.

SELECT date_format(STR_TO_DATE(concat(substr(datetime_uploaded ,6,2),"-",substr(datetime_uploaded ,9,3),"-",substr(datetime_uploaded ,13,4)),'%d-%M-%Y'),'%Y-%M')
FROM  OpsMetrics

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %b %Y %T:%f')
```

The NOW() returns the present datetime and you can replace it with other datetime that you want

Comment: How you get it the data? Via php variable?Set in the upload_datetime column in your database table the TYPE to DATETIME

Answer (score 0):

> In my database table one field upload_datetime is there and it is having a value like Mon, 02 Jan 2017 15:46:23 GMT.

This statement might be a bit misleading, because we don't need to be particularly concerned with how a `datetime` is stored internally.  Your exact question is to how to *format* that `datetime` in a certain way.

The [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function is one way to go here.  It accepts as input a time column, and a format mask, and returns a formatted string.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(upload_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS upload_formatted
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: I have run this query **select DATE_FORMAT('Mon, 02 Jan 2017 15:46:23 GMT', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') from Dual**

Comment: @krishnpatel We have zero knowledge of what type that column is, except that its name bears the term `datetime`.  If he is storing his dates as text, this is another problem altogether and he should not be converting to another text format but rather to date.

Comment: @krishnpatel And you don't need `from Dual` in your query, this is MySQL not Oracle.